# How can get the key of my IndexedDB val using idbKeyval?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I am using the **idbKeyval** library to save/retrieve data from IndexedDB local storage. I have a function to iterate through all my keys and get each corresponding object. However, when I retrieve each object (`val`), I need to know its corresponding key (that is how I correlate the object with an element in the DOM). But since the IndexedDB (and idbKeyval) api is asynchronous, I lose reference to the corresponding key. Is there a way that I can retrieve the corresponding `key` when I retrieve my `val`? Below is a snippet that better describes what I am trying to do:

```
var customStore = new idbKeyval.Store('my-db', 'offline-transactions');
idbKeyval.keys(customStore)
    .then(function (keys) {
        for (var i in keys) {
            var key = keys[i];
            var val = idbKeyval.get(key, customStore)
                .then(function (val) {

                    //THIS WORKS:
                    console.log(val);

                    //THIS DOES NOT WORK:
                    console.log(key);
                    //'KEY' IS OUT OF SCOPE HERE
                    //WHAT IS A GOOD WAY TO GET THE CORRESPONDING KEY FOR MY VAL HERE?

                });
        }
    });
```

And I am using the idbKeyval library: https://github.com/jakearchibald/idb-keyval

Answer (score 1):

There are <strike>two</strike> three solutions to this. You can either create an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) (the old way) and set a local variable to "copy" the variable from your loop:

```
.then(function(val) {
    (() => {
        var localKey = key;
        // ...
        // localKey will be preserved since it's encapsulated
        // in its own functional scope
    })();
}
```

Or you can use the more elegant [`Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) ES6 method:

```
keys.forEach((key) => {
    var val = // ...
    // No need to copy key here since we're in a new functional
    // scope by the nature of .forEach
});
```

Both methods essentially work the same -- you're preserving a variable by creating a new functional scope for each iteration of your loop.

Hope that helps clarify things a little.

**EDIT**

I missed the simplest* solution: using `let` or `const` in your for loop instead of `var`. This works because `let` and `const` have block scope instead of function scope. [This article helps explain that.](https://medium.com/@mautayro/es6-variable-declaration-for-loops-why-const-works-in-a-for-in-loop-but-not-in-a-normal-a200cc5467c2) So:

```
for (var i in keys) {
    const key = keys[i];
    // ...
    // key will be preserved in block
}
```

Personally, I'd prefer `Array.forEach` just because it looks simpler and protects you from ever having to worry about what scope you're in.

**Simplest: I had no idea until a moment ago.*